# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll, Visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm learning software developer and got this project of git hub to learn. https://github.com/the-best-flash/CSharpMiner

The project's creator give us the follow instructions to execute this project in visual studio, when I execute the step 3 (Select "Build -> Build Solution") appear this error:

[image]

**project's instructions:**

1. Load the solution file. *.sln
2. Change the dropdown that says "Debug" to say "Release"
3. Select "Build -> Build Solution"
4. Navigate to the CSharpMinerProgram\bin\Release folder and copy the .exe, and .dll files to wherever you want to run the program from. (ex. C:\CSMiner)
5. Make a \bin folder wherever you put the .exe (ex. C:\CSMiner\bin)
6. Copy the .dll files from CSharpMinerProgram\bin\Release\bin to the \bin folder you just made.
7. Create a "config.conf" file in the same folder as the .exe (ex. C:\CSMiner\bin) you can follow the example further down.
8. Right click on the .exe and make a shortcut. Copy the shortcut to your desktop.

---

*I already have made the step 2*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't *build* the solution, you *debugged* it instead. Debugging means running it, and it will throw an exception because it can't find the config file, which will be created on step 7. None of step 1-8 talk about debugging or running the program. Running the program with correct config file should work.